# writing equations one under another at same numbering

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I have written 3 equations and I want it to be displayed as following:

```
equation1=....     (1)

equation2=....     (2)
equation3=....
```

Which means that equation 2 and 3 are at the same `\begin{equation}`

I have tried the following code however I get errors:

```
\begin{equation}
    \gamma_{T}=tan^{-1}\frac{-V_{T2}}{V_{T1}} \
\end{equation}

The acceleration components of the ballistic target can be expressed in terms of the target weight $W$ , reference area $S_{ref}$, zero lift-drag $C_{D0}$ and gravity $g$.

\begin{align*} 

    \frac{dV_{T1}}{dt}=\frac{-F_{Drag}}{m}cos\gamma_{T}=\frac{-QS_{ref}C_{D0}g}{W}cos\gamma_{T}=
    \frac{-Qg}{\beta}cos\gamma_{T}

     \\

    \frac{dV_{T2}}{dt}=\frac{F_{Drag}}{m}sin\gamma_{T}-g=\frac{QS_{ref}C_{D0}g}{W}sin\gamma_{T}-g=
    \frac{Qg}{\beta}sin\gamma_{T}-g\

\end{align*}
```

Comment: In your code, do not use blank lines inside any math environment...it will produce errors

Comment: That solved the problem however its not showing the number (2) next to the equation like it did when i used \begin{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors come from leaving blank lines in math mode. I guess you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{T}=\tan^{-1}\frac{-V_{T_2}}{V_{T_1}}
\end{equation}
The acceleration components of the ballistic target can be expressed in terms of the
target weight $W$, reference area $S_\mathrm{ref}$, zero lift-drag $C_{D0}$ and gravity $g$.
\begin{align} 
\frac{dV_{T_1}}{dt} &= \frac{-F_\mathrm{Drag}}{m} \cos\gamma_{T}
 = \frac{-Q S_\mathrm{ref} C_{D0} g}{W} \cos\gamma_{T}
 = \frac{-Q g}{\beta} \cos\gamma_{T}
  \\
\frac{dV_{T_2}}{dt} &= \frac{F_\mathrm{Drag}}{m} \sin\gamma_{T}-g
 = \frac{Q S_\mathrm{ref} C_{D0} g}{W} \sin\gamma_{T}-g 
 = \frac{Q g}{\beta} \sin\gamma_{T}-g \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the two equations kind of belong together, a `split` environment, which gives you a centred number, may be more appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\gamma_{T}=\tan^{-1}\frac{-V_{T_2}}{V_{T_1}}
\end{equation}
The acceleration components of the ballistic target can be expressed in terms of the
target weight $W$, reference area $S_\mathrm{ref}$, zero lift-drag $C_{D0}$ and gravity $g$.
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\frac{dV_{T_1}}{dt} &= \frac{-F_\mathrm{Drag}}{m} \cos\gamma_{T}
 = \frac{-Q S_\mathrm{ref} C_{D0} g}{W} \cos\gamma_{T}
 = \frac{-Q g}{\beta} \cos\gamma_{T}
  \\
\frac{dV_{T_2}}{dt} &= \frac{F_\mathrm{Drag}}{m} \sin\gamma_{T}-g
 = \frac{Q S_\mathrm{ref} C_{D0} g}{W} \sin\gamma_{T}-g 
 = \frac{Q g}{\beta} \sin\gamma_{T}-g
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `equation` and `split` for the second display.